# Are there any TeamCity plugins that'll allow me to use Hyper-V for cloud agents?

Tags: teamcity

We're currently moving most of our internal servers to Hyper-V VMs. At some point we'll do the same for our TeamCity build agents.

I'm wondering whether we can use the Cloud Agent feature of TeamCity to elastically spin up VMs when needed. Is this possible? Is there a plugin for this? We're using System Center Virtual Machine Manager, if that makes it easier.

Comment: Did you ever figure way to get this working? We are looking at exactly the same problem

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are no out of the box plugins for System Center. However, there are two plugins which can be used as a reference if you chose to write your own:

- http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Cloud-VMWare+plugin
- http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Local+Cloud

Answer (score 1):

You could always use PowerShell for virtual machine management within your build process. If I remember correctly, Virtual Machine Manager is just a gui facade for executing PowerShell commands and gives you the ability to copy and paste the commands before executing.